# How do I collapse all entities to just headers when editing an Entity Framework EDMX model in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

Each block representing an entity has an icon to collapse it to its header (hiding all properties from the diagram) in the header's right-top corner. How do I collapse them all without clicking each one manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to assign a key to the command as it does not have one and I cannot find any context menu that contains it...

```
Tools>Options>Keyboard>Show Commands Containing: OtherContextMenus.MicrosoftDataEntityDesignContext.Diagram.CollapseAll
```

Comment: 8 years later, still going strong!